# Knockout js star rating "value not get cleared"

Tags: css, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using Knockout js for star binding.Its working only for first time when the page is loaded.when i select some 2 star out of 5 start for first time it gives me value correctly,After that  the value is not cleared and i cant able to select any of the stars.Need some help in it.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.starRating = {
 init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
  console.log(valueAccessor);
   $(element).addClass("starRating");
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      $("<span>").appendTo(element);
        $("span", element).each(function (index) {
            $(this).hover(
                function () { $(this).prevAll().add(this).addClass("hoverChosen") },
                function () { $(this).prevAll().add(this).removeClass("hoverChosen") }
            ).click(function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                console.log(observable)
                observable(index + 1);
                window.localStorage.setItem("star", observable());
            });
        });
      },
      update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        $("span", element).each(function (index) {
            $(this).toggleClass("chosen", index < observable());
        });
      }
    };

  //HTML
  <div id="divstarRating">
  <span id="feedStar" data-bind="starRating: UserFeedpoints"> </span>
            </div>


 //css

 .starRating span {
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 background-image: url(../star.png);
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-position: -24px 0;
 }

 .starRating span.chosen {
    background-position: 0 0;
 } 

.starRating:hover span {
 background-position: -24px 0;  
 transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
 }

 .starRating:hover span.hoverChosen {
     background-position: 0 0;
     transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  }
```

Comment: Generally, you should not be global-querying (like `$("<span>")`). You should be doing `$(element).find("<span>")` instead.

Comment: i dont have any problem in binding,only cant change the value once i select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value updates as expected for me. I commented out the localStorage because that's forbidden in a snippet.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.starRating = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    console.log(valueAccessor);
    $(element).addClass("starRating");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      $("<span>").appendTo(element);
    $("span", element).each(function(index) {
      $(this).hover(
        function() {
          $(this).prevAll().add(this).addClass("hoverChosen")
        },
        function() {
          $(this).prevAll().add(this).removeClass("hoverChosen")
        }
      ).click(function() {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        console.log(observable)
        observable(index + 1);
        //window.localStorage.setItem("star", observable());
      });
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $("span", element).each(function(index) {
      $(this).toggleClass("chosen", index < observable());
    });
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  UserFeedpoints: ko.observable()
});
```

```css
.starRating span {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e5/Yellow_Star.png);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: -24px 0;
}

.starRating span.chosen {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.starRating:hover span {
  background-position: -24px 0;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
}

.starRating:hover span.hoverChosen {
  background-position: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="divstarRating">
  <span id="feedStar" data-bind="starRating: UserFeedpoints"> </span>
  <div data-bind="text: UserFeedpoints"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah at first time it works,but after selecting i am returning different View1,and again i come back to view 2 which consist of star rating,the previous selected value does not get clear and i am unable to select too,hover does not work

Comment: What do you mean "I am returning different View1"?

Comment: I got 2 different page,first page i am displaying total number of star selected and in second page i have star rating (above code),Once i select star rating I ll be redirecting back to first page,After if i redirect to page 2 the selected star rating is not get clear and i cant selcet star  again hover will be not removed and it keeps previously selceted star

Comment: No, i am not changing anything

Comment: yep,i change the value of UserFeedpoints,Now on page 2 load star rating is clear the value,But now if i click on the star its not getting hover and not selected

Comment: I tried, second time when i select the star its give value but "chosen" class is not append to span tag

Comment: @custom binding on page load update is called but after that only init is called not update